# Can I add / insert an element into my ElementCollection with a JPA Repository Query?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I'm writing a Spring Boot app using an H2 file-based database. I have a few threads running in parallel, so I'm trying to find the best way to add elements to my Entity's embedded Set of Strings - an ElementCollection.

Fetching the full entity just to modify one field and save the whole entity, even though I've only changed one field, seems both clunky and risky - what if another thread is changing something else about the same entity - I wouldn't want to overwrite those unrelated changes.

Say I have an entity Product:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String description;
    private boolean soldOnline;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = EAGER)
    private Set<String> statesWhereAvailable = new HashSet();
}
```

And I have one thread going through and initializing the `boolean soldOnline` flag, and another thread going through and adding to the set of distinct states where people can purchase this product in-store. In the event of concurrent updates to the same Product, I wouldn't want the second thread to undo changes made in the first, because it happened to fetch the Entity before the first thread finished saving.

I'm hoping there's a way to write a Jpa Repository query to update that ElementCollection, but I can't find any examples anywhere. I'm hoping to be able to write something like this:

```java
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "update Product p " +
            "set i.statesWhereAvailable = i.statesWhereAvailable + :state " +
            "where p.id = :id")
    void addVendorToRelatedVendors(@Param("id") int id,
                                   @Param("state") String state);
}
```

Any advice would be really appreciated!